# Is it possible to pass a list into includes variables with Django?

Tags: html, django, templates, templating

I'm trying to create a reusable sub template to use on my pages that's something like this:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
  <p>{{ copy }}</p>
  <ul>
    {% for list_item in list %}
    <li>{{ list_item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

But, I'm wondering if it's possible to pass a list into the include? Maybe something like this?

```
{% includes 'template.html' with list="['list_item1', 'list_item2']" %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use variables with same data on many pages you may want to use context processors. You can use zip() in return for your list if you are looking for this.

**context_processors.py (in correct app folder)**

```
def extras(request):
    var1 = item1
    var2 = item2
    
zipped_vars = zip(var1, var2)
return {'zipped_vars': zipped_vars}
```